# JPA base entity instantiate issue in dao layer when using @MappedSuperclass

Tags: java, spring, entity-framework, jpa, inheritance

I am aware that we could not instantiate abstract class, however the requirement that I have which requires to instantiate base entity class in dao layer and I am not sure which is most efficient way to resolve it.

Here is what I have in my base entity:

```
@MappedSuperClass 
public abstract class User implements Serializable{
@Id
@Column(name = "USER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int userId
.......
```

Now I have two child entity which are pointed to two different tables which has identical columns

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APP_ONE_USER")
public class AppOneUser extends User{
}
```

AND

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APP_TWO_USER")
public class AppOneUser extends User{
}
```

My persistence.xml file looks like this

```
<persistence-unit name="APP_ONE_USER"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.mycom.entity.AppOneUser</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
</persistence-unit>
<persistence-unit name="APP_TWO_USER"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.mycom.entity.AppTwoUser</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
</persistence-unit>
```

I created two instances of entityManagerBean in my spring configuration for each persistence unit. At run time based on externalized property I am invoking entityManager with one or the other persistence unit

```
public class EntityManagerProvider {

@PersistenceContext(unitName="APP_ONE_USER")
private EntityManager em1;

@PersistenceContext(unitName="APP_TWO_USER")
private EntityManager em2;


public EntityManager getCurrentEntityManager(String persistenceUnitFlag){

    if(persistenceUnitFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("appOne")){
        return em1;
    }
    return em2;
}
```

}

In my DAO implementation

@Autowired
    private EntityManagerProvider emProvider;

```
private @Value("${persistence.unit.flag}") String persistenceUnitFlag;

@PostConstruct
private void EntityManagerProvider(){
    this.manager =  emProvider.getCurrentEntityManager(persistenceUnitFlag);
}
```

Now In my service implementation I have to instantiate this User base entity to set values (because I have to retrieve fields from incoming request) while instantiating
Because base entity is abstract I can not instantiate.

If I remove abstract  from the base class no compilation error but while saving object I am getting unknown entity error

My DAO method looks like this

```
public void saveUser(User user) {
    manager.persist(user);

}
```

Comment: Here your entities are `AppOneUser` and `AppTwoUser`(Fix the code above). So unknown entity error is obvious when trying to save `User()`.
Why can't you use the entity classed for incoming request?

Comment: How can I use `AppOneUser` or `AppTwoUser` dynamically to persist in dao layer? to answer cant I use entity from incoming request, incoming request has entity which is not type of any of `AppOneUser` or `AppTwoUser`

Comment: "Mapped superclass inheritance allows inheritance to be used in the object model, when it does not exist in the data model. It is similar to table per class inheritance, **but does not allow querying, persisting, or relationships to the superclass**. Its main purpose is to allow mappings information to be inherited by its subclasses." https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance

Comment: Hey Alan, thanks much. Based on that I think I will have to change the approach :) Good stuff